# How to execute code after Rails console has loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How does one go about running code specifically ***after*** a console has loaded in Rails? All other answers and questions appear to revolve around running a hook at *some point*, but not necessarily ***after*** as I am seeking.

**Desired Result:**

```
> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.1)
pry(main)>
Welcome
```

I have attempted to use both the `console` hook and `initializer` hook with no success. e.g.

**Attempt 1:**

```
# config/application.rb

console do
  puts "Welcome"
end
```

**Result:**

```
> rails console
Welcome # Too early                                                              
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.1)
pry(main)>
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
# config/application.rb

initializer "welcome", after: :disable_dependency_loading do |app|
  puts "Welcome"
end
```

**Result:**

```
> rails console
Welcome # Too early                                                              
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.1)
pry(main)>
```

Comment: I am not certain of your desired result, but have you considered rails runner, i.e. "rails runner 'p Rails.env' "?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **When Using with IRB**

Create a .**irbrc** file (it should be root of your project) you should set conf for `IRB_RC`. Below is the file

```
#.irbrc
IRB.conf[:IRB_RC] = Proc.new do
  puts "Welcome"
end
```

**Output**

```
~/D/p/p/s/console_test> rc
Running via Spring preloader in process 60648
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
Welcome #<======= Desired Result
irb(main):001:0>
```

> **When Using with PRY**

Create a **.pryrc** file (it should be root of your project) you should set conf for `exec_string`. Below is the file

```
#.pryrc
class WelcomeClass

  def self.greet
    puts "Welcome"
  end
end

Pry.config.exec_string = WelcomeClass.greet
```

**Output**

```
 ~/D/p/p/s/console_test> rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 61794
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
Welcome #<======= Desired Result
[1] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an ".irbrc" in your root.  This is simply a regular Ruby script file where you can run code on IRB startup.  For examples, see [Tweaking IRB](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/04/23/tweaking-irb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a config/initializers like this:

```
# config/initializers/001_test_console.rb
module Rails::ConsoleMethods
  def self.included(base)
    puts "Welcome!"
  end
end
```

Note: I've not tried this with pry, just standard irb.

Comment: Should still work as of Rails 6, but monkey patching like this could break in future versions.